# Add series lines to bar chart in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Is there any way to add [series lines](http://peltiertech.com/series-lines-useful-or-chart-junk/) to stacked bar charts created by ggplot in R? I have looked around in the documentation - to no avail.

Comment: Please improve on your question. What does your data look like. Do you have a small subset you could share? If not, please provide a reproducible example. What have you tried so far and why do you think it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Interestingly, the source you link to gives a lot of recommendations for visualisations that don't use series lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, here is an example of how you might do something like that using the `mtcars` data set. This uses `dplyr` and `ggplot2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## Calculate 'y' for each cyl/vs pair
(mtcars_summary <-
     mtcars                        %>%
     arrange(cyl, vs)              %>%
     group_by(cyl, vs)             %>%
     summarise(count = n())        %>% # Count per cyl/vs pair
     group_by(cyl)                 %>% # Here to be explicit, but can be left out.
     mutate(count = cumsum(count)) %>% # Calculate 'y' for each cyl/vs pair
     ungroup)

##     cyl    vs count
##   (dbl) (dbl) (int)
## 1     4     0     1
## 2     4     1    11
## 3     6     0     3
## 4     6     1     7
## 5     8     0    14

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, fill = factor(vs))) +
    geom_bar() +
    geom_line(aes(cyl, count), data = mtcars_summary) +
    ggtitle('Data: mtcars')
```

[image]